# How to combine Flask-RESTPlus with Requests: HTTP for Humans?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, flask-restful, flask-restplus

I'm using **Flask-RESTPlus** to make an endpoint and using **Requests: HTTP for Humans** to scraping product details from one of e-commerce site.

I have got the product details perfectly using **Requests**, but when I combine it with **FLASK-RESTPlus**, I'm facing some problems.

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
@api.route('/product')
class ProductDetails(Resource):
    query_parser = api.parser()
    query_parser.add_argument('marketplace', required=True, location='args')

    def post(self, query_parser=query_parser):
        args = query_parser.parse_args()
        url = args['marketplace']

        try:
            response = requests.post(
                url=args,
                json={
                     'url': url
                }, timeout=60
           )
            }
        except Exception as e:
           return {
                'status': 'error',
                'message': str(e)
            }
```

When I try to access the endpoint

```
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/product?marketplace=http://xx.xx.xx.xx/v1/markeplace_name/url
```

am always got this error:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "No connection adapters were found for '{'marketplace': 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx/v1/market_place_name/url'}'"
}
```

The things that make me confuse are why I can get the product details before.

So, what's wrong with my code?, any example or source to learn would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing the `args` dict to `requests.post` as the url parameter. Requests validates that the url you supply to `.post()` is valid and a url that starts with `{'marketplace': ...}` is obviously an invalid url.

This part of the code:

```
response = requests.post(
    url=args,
    json={
         'url': url
    }, timeout=60
)
```

And `args = query_parser.parse_args()`.

As you asked for source to help you learn, this is the code where requests checks the adapter at the start of the url which you can find in the sourcecode [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/eaab47f033cae3bd443abb6707dfc30ae3482c36/requests/sessions.py#L719):

```
def get_adapter(self, url):
    """
    Returns the appropriate connection adapter for the given URL.
    :rtype: requests.adapters.BaseAdapter
    """
    for (prefix, adapter) in self.adapters.items():

        if url.lower().startswith(prefix.lower()):
            return adapter

    # Nothing matches :-/
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
```

The `self.adapters.items()` that is used to check the url comes from [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/eaab47f033cae3bd443abb6707dfc30ae3482c36/requests/sessions.py#L415):

```
# Default connection adapters.
self.adapters = OrderedDict()
self.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter())
self.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter())
```

And the [`mount()`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/eaab47f033cae3bd443abb6707dfc30ae3482c36/requests/sessions.py#L738) method essentially maps the expected url prefix to one of requests' connection adapter types in the `self.adapters` dict.